# Is it possible to use external enums (outside message definitions) with protocol buffers?

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers

I need to store enumns inside a PB message that are defined outside the PB message definitions. Is it possible at all & how?

Comment: For java, you might try looking at protostuff, which I gather is more runtime-flexible than the official implemetation.

Comment: You could either use their string representation, or convert them to ints.

Answer (score 12):

It's possible. Look at [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/FNuHUqXDITw) for more info.
I like the suggestion to define enums in a seperate .proto file. like

enums.proto

```
enum A
{ 
   FIRST = 1;
   SECOND = 2;
}

enum B { ... }
```

other.proto

```
import "enums.proto";

message SOMEMESSAGE
{
  required A myenum = 1;
}
```